# Add select buttons to HTML without moving other elements

Tags: html, css, button, select

I have created a HTML document which contains multiple buttons. I have added these buttons inside a DIV id named 'buttons'. I now want to add a sort by button to the HTML page. This sort button should be on the same line as the other buttons, To do this, I have created a new DIV id inside 'buttons'. This code displays the sort button above the other buttons. Not inline.

I want to display the sort button inline with the rest of the elements. However, the other buttons should not move. How could I do this.

An example of the code:

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="sort-by-buttons">
    <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="price">Price</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('jacket')">Jacket</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just get rid of `<div id="sort-by-buttons">` or make that div inline. By default, divs are block level elements

Comment: or add `display: flex` to the div with the id of `buttons`.

Comment: I want to keep the other buttons in the center of the page. Those buttons should not move.

Comment: Nothing in the code you posted is centered

Answer (score 0):

Style the div and buttons:

```html
<div id="sort-by-buttons" style="display:inline;">
  <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')" style="display:inline;">All</button>
<button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('jacket')" style="display:inline;">Jacket</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for this problem:

## Solution 1

**Remove the container div `#sort-by-buttons`.**

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="price">Price</option>
  </select>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('jacket')">Jacket</button>
</div>
```

*If **Solution 1** is not possible, because you need `#sort-by-buttons` for some reason, you can have a look on the following two solutions:*

## Solution 2

**Add `display: flex` to the container div `#buttons`.**

```css
#buttons {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="sort-by-buttons">
    <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="price">Price</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('jacket')">Jacket</button>
</div>
```

## Solution 3

**Make `#sort-by-buttons` `inline-block`.**

```css
#sort-by-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div id="sort-by-buttons">
    <select name="sort-by" id="sort-by">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="price">Price</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('all')">All</button>
  <button class="button-value" onclick="filterProduct('jacket')">Jacket</button>
</div>
```